# Truffle compile fails: could not find file from any sources

Tags: truffle, truffle-compile

I'm following the steps of [this tutorial](http://www.dappuniversity.com/articles/blockchain-app-tutorial). I created a simple contract, TodoList.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract TodoList {
    uint public taskCount = 0;
}
```

Then I run `truffle compile` and get this error message

```
Error: Could not find .../todolist/contracts/TodoList.sol from any sources
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-resolver/index.js:76:1
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/async/internal/onlyOnce.js:12:1
    at next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/async/whilst.js:68:1)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-resolver/index.js:64:1
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-resolver/fs.js:85:1
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/async/internal/once.js:12:1
    at replenish (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/async/internal/eachOfLimit.js:61:1)
    at iterateeCallback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/async/internal/eachOfLimit.js:50:1)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/async/internal/onlyOnce.js:12:1
    at ReadFileContext.callback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-resolver/fs.js:81:1)
    at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:242:13)
Truffle v5.0.2 (core: 5.0.2)
Node v11.12.0
```

The file is there. If I remove that file, truffle compiles the  `Migrations.sol` automatically generated by `truffle init` without errors.

When I edit TodoList.sol with VSCode and try to compile it with the Solidity plugin, it doesn't complain, but it doesn't generate any output in the build folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was I edited the file in VSCode, but autosave was turned off. So this is the error message you get if you have an empty file in the contracts directory.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and as suggested above, i just went into sublime (source code editor) and saved the work and then "sudo truffle compile" worked.